# ESX - Initialization for vmfs2 failed with -1

Tags: vmware-esx

I recently purchases a bunch of R710's from Dell. I installed VMWare ESX on them. The installation process finishes without a problem; however once ESX boots the following error displays at the botton with red letters:

```
00:00:02:21.493 cpu11:4119) mod:2971: Initialization for vmfs2 failed with -1
```

I installed on two different servers and the same error appears.

The curious thing is that if I install ESXi 3.5 or 4 there is not problem. What does this problem mean, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that usually a management network misconfiguration error - you're not 100% clear, are you getting this on ESX4i - if so is it update 1/1a?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004858